# Creating android shape that keeps proportions

Tags: android, xml, shapes

How do I create an XML ressource shape that looks like a perfect circle no matter which object it is applied to? When I try to add it as a background to a button, it becomes a oval in stead of a circle.

Comment: use a `ShapeDrawable` with a custom `Shape` class where you draw whatever you want

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:shape="ring" android:innerRadiusRatio="5"
android:visible="true" android:thickness="4dp" 
 >
<stroke android:color="#654321"
    android:width="2dp"/>
<solid android:color="#123456"/>


</shape>
```